# cx_freeze - opens command window when running ffmpeg.exe or ffplay.exe through the GUI of the program created - how to hide this?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, ffmpeg, cx-freeze

I have built an MSI using cx_freeze for my python program tool.box.

Everything works great - however, I implemented this snippet in my setup.py:

```
base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"
```

to hide the cmd window that would typically open when you run the final .exe cx_freeze produces.

This works fine, and now when I launch, I do not see this blank cmd window.

However - in my program, I have a few buttons that call ffplay.exe and ffmpeg.exe - previously, without that snippet, I could run the program and when I clicked those buttons no CMD window would appear - now, however, it does - and it shows the output of ffplay or ffmpeg.

In my main.py, I have the following commands:

```
command_play = [ffplay_path, originalAudio, "-ss", str(actual_start_segment), "-t", "10", "-nodisp", "-autoexit"]

ffmpeg_command = FFmpeg(
            inputs={originalAudio: None},
            outputs={new_filename: ['-ss', str(actual_start_segment), '-to', str(actual_end_segment), '-async', '1', '-strict', '-2', '-ar', '44100', '-ab', '56k', '-ac', '1', '-y']}
        )
```

Both of which are set to not display the CMD window.

They only seem to do so when I compile. Any suggestions on how I can hide these so my GUI based program doesn't have CMD windows appearing when the end user utilises it's features?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution in the end, which is using the new CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag that’s in Python 3.7.

New code when calling ffplay or ffmpeg looks like this;

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

def play_beginning(command_play):

    subprocess.Popen(command_play, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```